# How to pass parameter in LIKE query of IBM Db2 with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, database, db2

i'm trying to execute a query from ibm db2 to ibm watson assistant using node.js 12. Below you can see the code that i am using and it works well for the function `fetchHSCode()` where the values retrieved from database are integers. However for `fetchName()` it is not working since the values are in varchar format.
The error obtained is

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'\n

I am having problem to write the query

> 'SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity", "Commodity_Code" FROM "PKD20375"."TRADES" WHERE "Commodity" LIKE '%?%'; '

Note that the double quotes("") between the tables column and table name is needed to run the query. It is not working without using double quotes.

```
var ibmdb = require('ibm_db');

// Retrieve HS code information
function fetchHSCode(dsn, hscode) {
    try {
        var conn = ibmdb.openSync(dsn);
        var data = conn.querySync('SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity_Code", "Commodity" FROM "PKD20375"."TRADES" WHERE "Commodity_Code"=?;', [hscode]);
        conn.closeSync();

    var resString = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        resString += data[i]['Commodity'] + "\n";
    }

    // Return both generated string and data
    return {
        result: resString, data: data, input: hscode
    };
} catch (e) {
    return {
        dberror: e
    }
}
}

// Retrieve product from name
function fetchName(dsn, productName) {
    try {
         var conn = ibmdb.openSync(dsn);
         var data = conn.querySync('SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity", "Commodity_Code" FROM "PKD20375"."TRADES" WHERE "Commodity" LIKE '%?%'; ', [productName]);
         conn.closeSync();
         var resString = "";
         for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             resString += data[i]['Commodity'] + "\n";
         
     }
     
     // Return both generated string and data
     return {
         result: resString, data: data, input: productName
     };
} catch (e) {
    return {
        dberror: e
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you mean you need to escape single quotes? `'\'%?%\''` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape single quotes since you have single quotes inside your string so it has to be escaped `\'` as following

```
 var data = conn.querySync('SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity", "Commodity_Code" FROM "PKD20375"."TRADES" WHERE "Commodity" LIKE \'%\' || cast(? as varchar(150)) || \'%\'; ');
```

In javascript, if you try to assign a string using an apostrophe in the middle of a single-quoted string, for example

```
const brokenString = 'I'm a broken string';
```

will get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifie`

so you can solve it by use double-quoted string

```
const nonbrokenString = "I'm a broken string";
```

or escape single quotes using the backslash

```
const nonbrokenString = 'I\'m a broken string';
```

Comment: The `?` symbol doesn't denote a parameter marker in your example. It's inside the string constant. It should look like `LIKE \'%\' || cast(? as varchar(100)) || \'%\'`.